# Mono.Cecil - Issues calling generic method

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I am having issues trying to call Nullable.Value when creating a Instruction. I am doing the following.

```
ModuleDefinition module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll");

TypeReference boolean = module.GetType("System.Boolean", true);
TypeReference nullableBoolean = module.GetType("System.Nullable`1", true).MakeGenericInstanceType(boolean);
TypeDefinition typeDefinition = nullableBoolean.Resolve();

MethodDefinition get_HasValue = typeDefinition.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_HasValue");
MethodDefinition get_Value = typeDefinition.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_Value");
MethodReference methodReference = module.Import(get_Value);

processor.Create(OpCodes.Call, methodReference);
```

When I insert these instructions it looks along the following in ILSpy, and if I try to run the code with it looking like this it gives "InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code"

```
call instance bool [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1::get_HasValue()
call instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1::get_Value()
```

**EDIT**

After some messing around I was able to get a bit closer to what it should be. The IL from Cecil matches the IL from compile generate code but now I am getting an error. I am going to include the code that I am using along with what I am editing.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Nullable' from assembly due to value type mismatch.
```

https://gist.github.com/7H3LaughingMan/311662c07b8bf8f8d2c6 https://gist.github.com/7H3LaughingMan/b606e99849f4d8addfc4 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7231478/Test.exe

Comment: checkout this article if you are using VS2015 https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/187

Comment: @MethodMan that doesn't help. I am not using Fody nor do I have the anything regarding NotifyPropertyWeaverMsBuildTask.WeavingTask in my csproject.

Comment: Compare IL generated by Mono.Cecil and the one by C# compiler first to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I looked into this and was a ble to match Compiler Generated IL but now I am getting an error. I updated my post.

Comment: Please could you post a expected outcome of the code. I.e. what do you want the new code to look like?